# Can someone help me with the validation of a checkbox in an Access form?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have problems with the validation of an Access form, and more precisely with a checkbox, since Access tells me that the object does not support that property or that method.

My code to carry out the verification, evaluates each control of the form, and if its value is empty or null, it paints the background color of it orange, and if it is corrected, it returns it to white.

Since the checkbox object does not share the BackColor property with the textbox or combobox, I tried to use BorderColor, which is common to all three.

My code:

```
Private Sub ValidarCampos()
Dim FormActivo As Form
Dim control As control

Set FormActivo = Forms(0)

ValidaCampos = True
For Each control In FormActivo.Controls
    If (control.ControlType = 109 Or control.ControlType = 111 Or control.ControlType = 106) And control.Visible = True And control.Enabled = True Then 'Revisar el 106 (checkbox)
        If control.ControlType = 106 Then
            valor = control.TripleState
        Else
            valor = Trim(control.Value)
        End If
        Debug.Print valor
        'If (valor = "" Or IsNull(valor)) And control.Tag = "*" Then
        If (valor = "" Or IsNull(valor)) Then
            control.BorderColor = VBA.RGB(237, 125, 49)
            'MsgBox "No puede dejar nulo el campo " & control.Name, vbInformation, tiTulo
            If FormActivo.Controls(control.Name).Enabled = True Then
                FormActivo.Controls(control.Name).SetFocus
            End If
            ValidaCampos = False
            'Exit Function
            Exit Sub
        Else
            control.BackColor = VBA.vbWhite
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

**Clarification:**
The problem occurs with the "Enabled" property of the checkbox
When it evaluates to the checkbox, Access tells me that the object does not support that property or method.

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? What did you expect to happen under what circumstances and what actually happened?

Comment: In the `Else` case you still have `BackColor`. See also [Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Comment: @TomBrunberg What I need is to know what value the checkbox has, that's why I use the "TripleState" property that returns a string, but I can't get the code to work.

Comment: I have detected that the error is in the evaluation with the "If". It does not work well, since when the error appears, it is currently processing a label, which should not happen because the "If" is worded as follows:
"If (control.ControlType = 109 Or control.ControlType = 111) And control.Visible = True And control.Enabled = True Then"

Comment: Why do you assign ```valor``` to ```control.TripleState```? I think you want to set the TripleState property to TRUE.

Comment: posting a work around.  if anyone knows why the checkbox has a border color property that doesn't work I would like to hear the explanation

Comment: Checkbox is bound to query field and has the same name? Avoid that as bound query fields are availible in Controls-Collection too (but hidden AccessField), Add a suffix to Controls name. Problem maybe solved if you don't refer to Controls by name, as you already have the full reference to them in the `control` variable! `control.Enabled = True` in if criteria is totally valid!

Answer (score 0):

I've had trouble with the access checkbox not working properly twice before.  You can get around the checkbox by turning a label into a synthetic checkbox.  This also gets you the back color property.  I got the outline of the solution from Fred here:  http://www.justskins.com/forums/changing-check-box-colour-171415.html

put a label and a checkbox on a form.  set the checkbox visible property to false.  resize the label and set the label.border property to solid to make the label look like a checkbox.  Set the label font to wingdings.  then here is the code.

```
'in form codebehind
Private Sub labelthatlookslikeacheckbox_Click()
If Me.invisiblecheckbox.Value = -1 Then
Me.invisiblecheckbox.Value = 0
Me.labelthatlookslikeacheckbox.Caption = ""
Else
If IsNull(Me.invisiblecheckbox.Value) Then
Me.invisiblecheckbox.Value = -1
Me.labelthatlookslikeacheckbox.Caption = Chr(254)
Else
Me.invisiblecheckbox.Value = Null
Me.labelthatlookslikeacheckbox.Caption = Chr(110)
End If
End If
Me.Refresh 'update display
    End Sub

'in a module
Private Sub ValidarCampos()
Dim FormActivo As Form
Dim control As control
Set FormActivo = Forms(0)
ValidaCampos = True
For Each control In FormActivo.Controls
If (control.ControlType = acCheckBox) Then
    If (control.Name = "invisiblecheckbox") And IsNull(control.Value) Then
    FormActivo.Controls("labelthatlookslikeacheckbox").BackColor = VBA.RGB(237, 125, 49)
    Else
    FormActivo.Controls("labelthatlookslikeacheckbox").BackColor = vbWhite
    End If
    'HANDLE OTHER CHECKBOXES HERE
    'if going generic one solution is to use a checkbox and label naming convention then parse control.name
Else
    If (control.ControlType = acTextBox Or control.ControlType = acComboBox) Then
    'labels don't have an enabled control so we only test textboxes and comboboxes
    If control.Visible = True And control.Enabled = True Then
    valor = Trim(control.Value)
    Debug.Print valor
        If (valor = "" Or IsNull(valor)) Then
            control.BackColor = VBA.RGB(237, 125, 49)
            If FormActivo.Controls(control.Name).Enabled = True Then
                FormActivo.Controls(control.Name).SetFocus
            End If
            ValidaCampos = False
        Else
            control.BackColor = VBA.vbWhite
        End If
    End If
    End If
End If
Next 'control
End Sub
```

Top checkbox is the label:

[image]

Without Text highlighted :

[image]